# Fondo negro al rotar imagen python

Tags: python, imagen

¡Buenas!

Estoy intentado rotar una imágen, unos 10 grados. El problema es que cuando lo giro sale un fondo negro en la foto.

Así es como giro la imagen, con la ***libreria PIL.***

```
    def add_parts(self, item):
    """
    Crear imagen en blanco y añadir los elementos
    @return:
    """
    if self.opened:
        self.set_currency(item)
        # Coger parametros de dimension
        final_img_size = self.SETTINGS.get("CUSTOM_IMG_FINAL_SIZE")
        final_img_width = final_img_size.get("WIDTH")
        final_img_height = final_img_size.get("HEIGHT")
        # Crear imagen blanca
        final_img = Image.new(mode='RGB', size=(final_img_width, final_img_height), color=(255, 255, 255))
        # Coger partes de la imagen
        bottom_left = Image.open(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/static/cositas_de_espana/bottom-left.png')
        bottom_left_2 = Image.open(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/static/cositas_de_espana/bottom-left-2.png')
        logo = Image.open(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/static/cositas_de_espana/logo.png')
        top_right = Image.open(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/static/cositas_de_espana/top-right.png')
        # Colocar esquina inferior izquierda
        final_img.paste(bottom_left, (self.SETTINGS.get("PART_BOTTOM_LEFT").get("WIDTH"),
                                      self.SETTINGS.get("PART_BOTTOM_LEFT").get("HEIGHT")))
        # Colocar esquina superior derecha
        final_img.paste(top_right, (self.SETTINGS.get("PART_TOP_RIGHT").get("WIDTH"),
                                    self.SETTINGS.get("PART_TOP_RIGHT").get("HEIGHT")))
        # Colocar logo
        final_img.paste(logo, (self.SETTINGS.get("PART_LOGO").get("WIDTH"),
                               self.SETTINGS.get("PART_LOGO").get("HEIGHT")))
        # Colocar producto y girar∫
        final_img.paste(self.image.rotate(5, expand=True), (self.SETTINGS.get("COSITAS_PRODUCT_IMG").get("WIDTH"),
                                     self.SETTINGS.get("COSITAS_PRODUCT_IMG").get("HEIGHT")))


        ################
        #### PRICE #####
        ################
        # Precio a un lado de la imagen
    self.image = final_img

    return final_img
                                     self.SETTINGS.get("COSITAS_PRODUCT_IMG").get("HEIGHT")))
```

la foto sale asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Sabeis como puedo quitar ese fondo negro o darle otro color?

O si conoceís alguna otra librería mas útil, que pueda utilizar.

¡Gracias!

Comment: Colocas tu código completo para poder ayudarte mejor.? O por lo menos el metodo que usas

Comment: Acabo de añadir el metodo que utilizo, lo que hago es, en un fondo blanco ir poniendo partes y una de esas partes es un la foto de la chica, entonces la giro y cuando la muestro sale girada pero con el fondo negro.

Comment: Veo que estas definiendo el fondo en blancon con ´color=(255, 255, 255)´, pero luego le estas pegando las imagenes en partes, has pensado que esas imagenes estan colocandote el color negro de fondo.?

Comment: Solo me pasa con esta imagen. Es como si al girar la imagen, la girase dentro de un rectangulo y sale con fondo negro. No se si se podra darle a esta imagen en concreto un fondo blanco o algo asi.

Comment: La imagen es jpeg? Tiene algo en especial esa imagen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La rotacion de la imagen debe crear un marco o *padding* para llenar los espacios vacios que crea.

Si utilizar un esquema con canal alfa RGBA en lugar de RGB. Puedes usar el siguiente truco para pintarlo.

La solucion resulta de hacer una composicion entre una imagen blanca y la que tiene el *padding* transparente para lograr pintarlo blanco, lo cual puedes hacer de la siguiente manera, por ejemplo:

```
# original image
img = Image.open('test.png')
# converted to have an alpha layer
im2 = img.convert('RGBA')
# rotated image
rot = im2.rotate(22.2, expand=1)
# a white image same size as rotated image
fff = Image.new('RGBA', rot.size, (255,)*4)
# create a composite image using the alpha layer of rot as a mask
out = Image.composite(rot, fff, rot)
# save your work (converting back to mode='1' or whatever..)
out.convert(img.mode).save('test2.bmp')
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252170/specify-image-filling-color-when-rotating-in-python-with-pil-and-setting-expand)

Comment: Muchas gracias esto es lo que necesitaba.